# AC DC Analysis of diode

Tags: ac, dc, diodes

in the following circuit:

[image]

Im looking to find what \$v_D(t)\$ is given \$V_γ = 0.7 V\$ and \$r_f = 0\$.

Now when doing the DC analysis, find that \$VDQ = 0.7 V.\$ 
But im having trouble finding IDQ.

Would that be \$4.7/7V\$?

Once, I find that I use \$r_d = VT/IDQ\$ correct?

Thanks you all very much!

Comment: @Thanos - you have edited this and therefore you presumably understand what Vγ, rd, rf, VT, VDQ and IDQ refer to. Maybe you can point out these nodes and currents on the diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DC analysis:

The voltage drop across the diode is 0.7 volts, and the DC current through the diode is only determined by the resistor:

$$IDQ=\frac{7V-0.7V}{4700\Omega}=1.34mA$$

For the AC analysis you can use the differential resistance

$$r_d=\frac{kT}{qIDQ}\approx\frac{0.025}{IDQ}\Omega=18.65\Omega\quad\text{(at room temperature)}$$

So for \$v_D(t)\$ we get

$$v_D(t)=-\frac{r_d}{r_d+4700\Omega}0.4\sin(\omega t)V=-1.58\sin(\omega t)mV$$

Comment: Sure! If the answer is useful for you, you can hit the Accept button to show that your question has been answered satisfactorily.